# Upload multi file from linux folder to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

now in Linux VM, I upload a single file with this command:
azure storage blob upload -q  /folder/file.txt  --container containerName

Is possible upload more file at the same time? (with a single command)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a loop like so

```
#!/bin/bash

export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT='your_account'
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY='your_access_key'

export container_name='name_of_the_container_to_create'
export source_folder=~/path_to_local_file_to_upload/*


echo "Creating the container..."
azure storage container create $container_name

for f in $source_folder
do
  echo "Uploading $f file..."
  azure storage blob upload $f $container_name $(basename $f)
  cat $f
done

echo "Listing the blobs..."
azure storage blob list $container_name

echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 1):

The command line does not have an option to bulk upload multiple files in one invocation. However, you can either use find or a loop to upload multiple files, or if doing this from Windows is an option, then you can look at using the AzCopy tool (http://aka.ms/azcopy).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a recent Python interpreter on your Linux VM and all of your files are in one directory then the Azure Batch and HPC team has released a code sample with some [AzCopy-like functionality on Python called blobxfer](https://github.com/Azure/blobxfer) that may help with your situation. The script permits full recursive directory ingress into Azure Storage as well as full container copy back out to local storage. [full disclosure: I'm a contributor for this code]